# Add average column

Tags: sql-server

How do I add an percentage column to the following query? I want to display the equivalent of (upgraded / needsupgrade * 100) in the fourth column, but this returns "0" in the "percent" column:

```
SELECT
    upgraded,
    needsupgrade,
    total,
    upgraded / needsupgrade * 100 AS 'percent done'
FROM
(
    SELECT count(id) AS upgraded
    FROM attempts
    WHERE needsupgrade = 1
) upgraded,
(
    SELECT count(id) AS needsupgrade
    FROM attempts
    WHERE needsupgrade = 0
) needsupgrade,
(
    SELECT count(id) AS total
    FROM attempts
) total
```

Comment: Using `100.0 * @upgraded / @needsupgrade` will work, though if you are dealing with large numbers this might be not the best idea.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is probably due to SQL Server returning an integer when doing division between to integers.
And that will probably be 0 in your case, you need to convert at least one of the fields to decimal.

```
SELECT
    upgraded,
    needsupgrade,
    total,
    (upgraded / convert(decimal, needsupgrade)) * 100 AS 'percent done'
FROM
(
    SELECT count(id) AS upgraded
    FROM attempts
    WHERE needsupgrade = 1
) upgraded,
(
    SELECT count(id) AS needsupgrade
    FROM attempts
    WHERE needsupgrade = 0
) needsupgrade,
(
    SELECT count(id) AS total
    FROM attempts
) total
```

Answer (score 1):

An int divided by and int will return a int

Just add some precision to your calculation

```
(upgraded / (needsupgrade+0.0)) * 100 AS 'percent done'
```

for Example

```
Select 25/100 Returns 0
While
Select 25/(100+.0) Returns 0.25
```

Comment: I dont understand why you where downvoted your answer is also correct, I upvoted you back.to 0

Comment: @GuidoG - To me this comes over as a hack. Adding "0.0" as a constant to a variable to convert it to a floating point? You really should be using `cast` or `convert`. Would you accept the same construct in C# code?